# How to fetch a ember model with a more complex url

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using EmberData and wonder how I can I fetch a model from path like this:

```
products/:id/comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using the default RESTAdapter, this is one possible way — although I'm not sure if it's the best one:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ProductCommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var productId = this.controllerFor('product').get('model').get('id');

    return App.Comment.find({ product_id: productId });
  }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.resource('product', { path: ':product_id' }, function() {
        this.route('comments');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: `controlleFor` is deprecated, one should do this kind of transformations in the routes serialize hook instead.

Comment: At least in Ember RC 6 `controllerFor` is deprecated inside of a controller, where one should use `needs` instead. As far as I know, it is not deprecated inside of the `model` hook of a router. Am I mistaken?

Comment: But does this means that I must create routes that I don't need just to fetch my model from the right path.

Comment: Are you talking about the url from you server api? If it is so, the default RESTAdapter won't work with nested resources. You'll have to create your own.